# Suppose $a,b$ are integers. If $4\mid(a^2 +b^2)$, then $a$ and $b$ are not both odd.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've tried using direct proof and contrapositive proof to prove this.
I'm stuck. Is anyone able to help solve or give me some hints?

Answer (score 1):

If $4|a^2+b^2$ then $a^2+b^2=4m$ for some integer $m$.

Now suppose that $a$ and $b$ are both odd. Then $a=2i+1$ and $b=2j+1$ for some integers $i,j$.

Then $a^2+b^2=4i^2+4i+1+4j^2+4j+1=4(i^2+i+j^2+j)+2$, which is a contradiction.

If you are comfortable with modular arithmetic, we would say that we can't have both $a^2+b^2\equiv 0$ mod $4$ AND $a^2+b^2\equiv 2$ mod $4$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $a$ and $b$ **are** both odd, if we show that this does not divide $4$ we have completed the proof. Then for some $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$,  $a=2n+1$ and $b=2m+1$. Now $$a^2=(2n+1)^2=4n^2+4n+1$$ and $$b^2=(2m+1)^2=4m^2+4m+1$$ So $$a^2+b^2=4n^2+4n+4m^2+4m+2$$ We must show that this does not divide $4$, i.e. we must show that $$\frac{a^2+b^2}{4}\notin\mathbb{Z}$$$$\frac{4n^2+4n+4m^2+4m+2}{4}=n^2+n+m^2+m+\frac12$$Since $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$ we get that this value is not an integer.

Comment: This is known as "proof by contradiction"